# AWS S3 file names / prefered method of managing files in a bucket

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket set up to host my static files for an EC2 instance.  (I'm still learning about the deployment process, so I am currently using Django's runserver command, not a real server, if that has any bearing on the problem.)  I uploaded my files in their folder structure, and I can connect to the EC2's IP address and see the static files as I need to.

But, when I log into AWS's console, all of the file names have been changed to what I am assuming is Date-Time followed by hexadecimal code.  I cannot recognize any of the files.  I've gone out and gotten the S3 Browser hoping that I would get more information that way, but, nope, all hex.  I cannot find the original file names (or folder information) anywhere.

I believe that buckets are actually flat storage, and that the 'folders' are really more for my ability to organize for development / direct within the HTML.  I was going to upload more static files, but not seeing any folders or even file names, I am confused as to how this should be done.  When you want to upload new files into an existing bucket, do you have to upload them as folders?

Also, what is the best (or industry-accepted) practice for being able to interact with the files in a Bucket?  If I wanted to delete a file in my bucket right now, I have no idea on how to find it.

Comment: From what I understand, what we would normally think of as a "file name" is stored as the "key" in an S3 bucket.   I've never used S3, so I can't give you any help from personal experience, but I'd expect this key to be visible somewhere.